# Tracking AWS Resouce Costs Per Cognito User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want my website to offer premium services to authenticated Cognito users, and so I want to be able to bill each user for the AWS resources they use.  How can I track my monthly AWS spend back to the individual Cognito user?  I see that I can assign cost allocation tags to user pools, but I'm looking for something at the user level, not the user pool level.  I also see that I can use "Attribute-Based Access Control" in an identity pool, and that I can get tags called "Tag key for Principal" that can be referenced in IAM policies, but I'm not seeing a way to get those tags to map to cost allocation tags in the billing console.

The main resources I'm thinking about tracking initially are S3 storage and Lambda compute.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I know of is the following:
https://aws.amazon.com/es/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-and-usage-reporting/

It may be what you need.

Comment: This report would probably be good, but the missing piece for me would be a cost allocation tag where the value of the tag is the Cognito user.